# Google drive push notifications from entire organizations drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm writing application that is supposed to scan each uploaded/modified file that meets some naming criteria. I need to set up a notification channel for entire drive of my organization, even users private directories. I found this resource but it requires authentication token for user (I suppose it's user that resources are being watched) https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

I have service account that I currently use to mock users I want to interact as https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = dir_path + '/../credentials.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('userMail@org.com')
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

That's how I currently access drive as a user I'd like to check. Is there any way to use that newly created service with delegated credentials to get authentication token required for drive push api?

Comment: If this is a gsuite domain then you can use the service account and delegate access to all of the users on the domain.  If not you will need to use Oauth2 to authorize each of the users and get permission to access their drive accounts.

Comment: @DaImTo what do you mean by delegate access to all of the users? Yes, it is gsuite domain.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation  service account will give you access to all users in the domain it just has to be set up by the admin of the domain.

Comment: @Isanaut are you familiar with [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)? This seems like the only way to solve your problem. Are you the adming for your domain?